24 bit integers that are exactly 3 bytes packed
I am writing a tool to port games written in C/C++ from the 24bit eZ80 to Windows/Linux. One of the issues is that int24_t doesn't exist on x86/x64.
typedef uint32_t uint24_t doesn't always work, especially with packed data and incrementing uint24_t* pointers. I tried _BitInt(24) in Clang C23, but I then found out that sizeof(_BitInt(24)) is 4 bytes, with -Wcast-align stating that the alignment for _BitInt(24) was also 4. I tried _ExtInt(24) but it also had a size of 4 bytes.
So far, I have only found two solutions where int24_t is exactly 3 bytes packed.
typedef struct int24_t {
    uint8_t n[3];
} int24_t;

The first being a struct. But this requires a lot of refactoring in the code, as int x = y + a * b on the eZ80 would become int24_t x = ADD_INT24(y, MUL_INT24(a, b)), which is not as readable.
class int24_t {
    private:
        uint8_t n[3];
};

The other solution I found was to use a C++ class, which is also exactly 3 bytes in Clang and GCC. Since this allows for operator overloading, expressions can be written normally int24_t x = y + a * b. However, since C and C++ are different languages, compiling C as C++ might not always work.
Are there any ways to have a packed int24_t type in C?
Edit: Such that int24_t can be used with infix notation x + y instead of function notation ADD(x, y)

I'd just change the integers to be int32_t.  It makes the data a little bit bigger but that's probably fine since you'll be running it on a much more powerful processor.  You might need to mask off the top 8 bits in a few places using &.

Why do you need the integers to be 3-bytes packed?  Using _BitInt(24) should give you the correct behaviour using the normal operators.  Behind the scenes, it is likely that functions are used — possibly inline functions — but the notation would work cleanly.  The only disadvantage would be the larger size, but is that really a problem on the target machines?  Are you really sure?

Can you give examples of the parts of the code that break if the size of it is 4 bytes instead of 3?

"Are there any ways to have a packed int24_t type in C?" No.

@Vortex 2728182818, "One of the issues is that int24_t doesn't exist on x86/x64." --> It is a compiler issue, not a hardware one.  Nothing prevents a compiler from making a 24-bit int24_t on a x86/x64 other than there is scant demand for it.

IIRC, MPLAB has 24-bit (u)int24_t.

@chux, the one thing that could prevent a compiler providing a 24-bit int24_t is if it would require padding bits in order to do so.  That's probably not an show-stopper on systems where CHAR_BIT is a factor of 24 (8, 12 or 24), but could be an issue on some platforms.

I think you are trying to solve the wrong problem. You focus on having the source code 100% compatible, instead of having the behavior 100% compatible.
I propose the following steps:

Just use uint32_t for the most part.
Find the places where (if any) e.g., a loop is implemented by overflowing a uint24_t. In those places, add an instruction similar to a%=(1<<24u).
Find the places where that data interfaces with other special data (e.g, registers). In those places, adapt the code to take care of data sizes, if needed.
Test and debug.

NOTE: You wrote: "I am writing a tool to port ..." instead of "I port ...". That goes towards my proposal: change as little as possible the original code, use the best at hand, adapt as you go. Otherwise, start writing an emulator to run the original code (hint: such emulators already exist, I guess).

Here's the implementation, but it's in C++:
#include <iostream>
#include <print>

struct int24_t {
    uint8_t n[3];
    int24_t() = default;
    // Converting constructor
    int24_t(int32_t x) : n{ uint8_t(x), uint8_t(x >> 8), uint8_t(x >> 16) } { }
    operator int32_t() const {
        return n[2] & 0x80
            ? (n[2] << 16) | (n[1] << 8) | n[0] | 0xFF000000
            : (n[2] << 16) | (n[1] << 8) | n[0];
    }
};

template <> // For formatted output
struct std::formatter<int24_t> : std::formatter<std::string> {
    auto format(int24_t p, format_context& ctx) const {
        return std::format_to(ctx.out(), "{}", p.operator int32_t());
    }
};

int main() {
    int32_t a32{ +1000 }, b32{ -1000 };
    int24_t a24{ a32 },   b24{ b32 };

    std::println("sizeof int24_t = {}",       sizeof int24_t);
    std::println("sizeof (int24_t[10]) = {}", sizeof(int24_t[10]));
    std::println("min int24_t: {}",           int24_t{ -8388608 });
    std::println("max int24_t: {}",           int24_t{ +8388607 });
    std::println("add: {} = {}", a32 + b32,   int24_t{ a24 + b24 });
    std::println("mul: {} = {}", a32 * b32,   int24_t{ a24 * b24 });
}

Result:
sizeof int24_t = 3
sizeof (int24_t[10]) = 30
...

Maybe it can be translated into C?

Because the C language does not support operator overloading, you need to write wrapper functions (such as add_int24() and int24_mul()) to perform these operations.
Use a struct with bit fields to represent a 24-bit integer.
typedef union {
    int8_t bytes[3];
    struct {
        int32_t value : 24;
    } bits;
} int24_t;

int24_t convert(int32_t x) {
    int24_t result;
    result.bits.value = x & 0xFFFFFF;
    // handle the sign extension manually
    if (x & 0x800000) {
        result.bits.value |= ~0xFFFFFF;
    }

    return result;
}

int24_t int24_add(int24_t a, int24_t b) {
    return convert(a.bits.value + b.bits.value);
}

int24_t int24_mul(int24_t a, int24_t b) {
    return convert(a.bits.value * b.bits.value);
}

Example usage:
    int24_t a = { .bits.value = 0x123456 };
    int24_t b = { .bits.value = -1 };
    int24_t c = int24_add(a, b);
    int24_t d = int24_mul(a, b);


The main goal I had in mind was that the int24_t type wouldn't need to be wrapped in Macros or function calls. It would take some time to refactor code from infix to function notation, and function notation is not as readable. Ideally, one should be able to call int24_t x = y + a * b

@Konstantin Makarov, Yes, you are right. I have corrected the code.

This int24_t is still 4 bytes!  The value is only 3 bytes, but the compiler still adds one padding byte for alignment.

Now it works in the required range from -8388608 to +8388607.

I don't think you're allowed to call your type int24_t - that name is reserved for the implementation.  And you probably need a static_assert(sizeof (int24_t) == 3) to prove there's no padding introduced.

@ Mooing Duck, yes, this int24_t  ocuppies 4 bytes.

@TobySpeight Yes, it definitely is a reserved name. Perhaps u24 might be a better option.

What do you expect result.bits.value |= ~0xFFFFFF; to be doing, when value is a 24-bit field?

With this implementation, there is no need to set the highest bits for a negative number. The definition of the bit field (: 24) is sufficient.
